# Meaning of munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer?

Tags: c

I am trying to solve a codewars problem https://www.codewars.com/kata/521c2db8ddc89b9b7a0000c1
Where the goal is to print the items of a 2d array in a snail like movement.

```
array = [[1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]]
snail(array) #=> [1,2,3,6,9,8,7,4,5]
```

Unfortunately I can't provide a main() function because it is possible to replicate this error only on the website. Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *snail(size_t *outsz, const int **mx, size_t rows, size_t cols) {
    int k = 0;
    int* result = (int*)malloc(rows*rows);
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int n = rows;
  
    while (n > 0) {
        for (int i = x; i < x + n; ++i){
            result[k] = mx[y][i];
            k++;
        } 

        n--; y++;

        for (int i = y; i < y + n; ++i){
            result[k] = mx[i][x + n];
            k++;
        } 

        for (int i = x + n - 1; i >= x; --i){
            result[k] = mx[y + n - 1][i];
            k++;
        } 

        n--;
 
        for (int i = y + n - 1; i >= y; --i){
            result[k] = mx[i][x];
            k++;
        } 

        x++;
    }
  
    *outsz = rows*rows;
    return result;
}
```

I am getting the correct array as output but if outsz(which is supposed to store the size of the output array) has the correct value, the test crashes. It gives a munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer.

Eventhough it is difficult to replicate without a main(), can you explain what this error means? What could be the possible solutions to fix this? If (outsz != correct size of result), the test doesn't crash (but of course the testcases fail). In some other threads I have read that it has something to do with free() but I still don't understand the why it crashes.

Comment: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Don't you think it's strange that the function prototype includes a parameter `cols` that you are not using for anything?  It's not clear from the CodeWars description, but I would expect that to be the number of columns in the grid. In that case, if `ncols` is greater than `nrows` in any of the test cases, then you will not be allocating enough space for your solution (nor computing the correct solution).  And if ever `ncols` is smaller than `nrows` then you'll probably be overrunning the bounds of `mx`.

Comment: `malloc(rows*rows)` -> `malloc(rows*rows* sizeof(*result))` I assume you're not allocating enough soace and corrupting memory outside the allocation. That is usually the cause of that particular error.

Comment: Did you try googling your error messge? It finds a bunch of previous SO questions that explain what it means and how to fix it.

Comment: More likely `malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(*result))`

Comment: @Barmar  While I agree that `rows * cols` makes the most sense, it looks like the dimensions are always the same (i.e., a square; description: `n x n`, C source comment: *"// The numbers of rows and cols are passed separately for historical reasons"*).

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. That fixed the error. Now I understand that I was allocating less memory. But why is sizeof(*result) used instead of sizeof(int)? Also, I did google the error but those other posts say that the error was because of free()ing pointers which were not obtained through malloc() but that wasn't the case here.

Comment: `sizeof(*result)` works even if the type of result is changed to something else, like `short` or `long long`. It is once less place for a mistake to be made.

Comment: @RetiredNinja OK understood. Does sizeof(*ptr) give the sizeof(data type whose address is stored in ptr)?

Comment: It is the size of the type pointed to.

Comment: In general, `sizeof expression` is the same as `sizeof(type of expression)`